# How can I eliminate the headers from my graph (using python and pandas to graph a CSV file)?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to graph data from a CSV file, however, I keep getting headers as if I were graphing to different things. I want to remove this (the orange line on the top left corner). Actually if I could remove the whole thing it would be better.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

headers = ['Espectro del plasma de Ag con energía de 30mJ', "tiempo (microsegundos) vs Voltaje (v)", " "]

df = pd.read_csv('TEK0000.csv', names=headers)

ax = df.set_index('Espectro del plasma de Ag con energía de 30mJ').plot()
ax.set_xlabel('tiempo (microsegundos)')
ax.set_ylabel('voltaje (V)')
plt.show()
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnTZS.png)

Comment: You can use usecols and eliminate that last ' ' in headers or we can filter your plotting dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
headers = ['Espectro del plasma de Ag con energía de 30mJ', "tiempo (microsegundos) vs Voltaje (v)"]

df = pd.read_csv('TEK0000.csv', names=headers, usecols=[0,1])
```

Or:

```
ax = df.set_index('Espectro del plasma de Ag con energía de 30mJ')['tiempo (microsegundos) vs Voltaje (v)'].plot()
```